# Alphabetical pairing of CSV elements while keeping first element constant in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, csv, python-itertools

How is it possible to take a CSV file with rows of varying lengths (up to 12 in practice) as input and then output a new CSV file where new rows consist of 
the 0th element of each row + each unique pair of elements (>0th) in alphabetical order?

The original row elements are not in alphabetical order.

Please see image for example input and output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbQgo.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) for reading & writing and [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for generating the pairs:

```
import csv
from itertools import combinations

with open('input.csv') as in_f, open('output.csv', 'w') as out_f:
    reader = csv.reader(in_f)
    writer = csv.writer(out_f)

    for row in reader:
        for combination in combinations(sorted(row[1:]), 2):
            writer.writerow(tuple(row[:1]) + combination)
```

Output:

```
0,A,B
1,A,B
1,A,C
1,B,C
2,A,B
2,A,C
2,A,D
2,B,C
2,B,D
2,C,D
```

Comment: Thanks @niemmi !
I'm using python 3.5 so I need to add a newline parameter in
open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_f 
or else the output.csv file had an empty row between lines

Also, was getting TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
so I only used 'w' and 'r' in the open statements.

Everything has worked except the unique pairs are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: @WhyNot: It should work if you change the output file mode from `wb` to `w`. I tested the original response on Python 2.7 where things work bit differently but now I updated the answer and tested it on 3.4. I doubt 3.5 would be any different compared to 3.4.

Comment: It works perfectly. The alphabetical sort is placing upper case letters ahead of lower case letters, so 'Zebra' is ordered before 'apple'. This was my confusion. Thanks again @niemmi